# Merge query from datagridview to database not executing sql, vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, merge

I'm having a problem executing a merge query from to update or insert values from a `DataGridView` table into a **sql server database table**. Here is my code below, it doesn't give me any errors or stoppages, however I recently noticed that it has been creating completely rows in my database table **dbo.schedule** which contain all **NULL** values even that key location, could someone please help me? I'm not very familiar with merge queries in sql so please point out issues with my syntax:

```
Dim query As String = String.Empty


query &= "DECLARE @TaskID nvarchar(8), @Task nvarchar(50), @Start_date datetime, @Due_date datetime, @Complete bit, @Task_Manager nvarchar(8), @JRID nvarchar(10), @Entered_By char(50), @Time_Entered datetime;"
query &= "MERGE INTO schedule USING (VALUES (@TaskID, @Task, @start_date, @Due_Date, @Complete, @Task_Manager, @JRID, @Entered_By, @Time_Entered)) AS t(TaskID, Task, start_date, Due_Date, Complete, Task_Manager, JRID, Entered_By, Time_Entered) "
query &= "ON schedule.TaskID = @TaskID WHEN MATCHED THEN"
query &= " UPDATE SET schedule.TaskID = t.TaskID, schedule.Task=t.Task, schedule.start_date=t.start_date, schedule.due_date=t.due_date, schedule.complete=t.complete, schedule.task_manager=t.task_manager, "
query &= "schedule.JRID=t.JRID, schedule.Entered_by=t.Entered_by, schedule.Time_Entered=t.Time_Entered"
query &= " WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (TaskID, Task, start_date, Due_Date, Complete, Task_Manager, JRID, Entered_By, Time_Entered)"
query &= " VALUES (@TaskID, @Task, @start_date, @Due_Date, @Complete, @Task_Manager, @JRID, @Entered_By, @Time_Entered);"


Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbLocations(0, 1))
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MainSchedule.DataGridView1.Rows
                If Not (row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing) Then
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", TNn)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Complete", "False")
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", row.Cells(0).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_date", row.Cells(1).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Due_Date", row.Cells(2).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JRID", txtJRID.Text)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task_Manager", row.Cells(3).Value)
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entered_By", GetUserName())
                    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time_Entered", Now)
                    NextTask()
                End If
            Next
        End With
        conn.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in case anyone is wondering, here is my new code:

```
    Connexion.Open()
                Dim query As String = String.Empty
                Dim keypos = 0

                query &= "UPDATE schedule SET Task = @Task, Complete = @Complete, Start_date = @Start_date, "
                query &= "Due_date = @Due_date, JRID = @JRID, Task_Manager = @Task_Manager, Entered_By = @Entered_By, Time_Entered = @Time_Entered "
                query &= "WHERE TaskID = @TaskID "
                query &= "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO schedule ( TaskID, Task, start_date, Due_Date, Complete, Task_Manager, JRID, Entered_By, Time_Entered)"
                query &= " VALUES ( @TaskID, @Task, @start_date, @Due_Date, @Complete, @Task_Manager, @JRID, @Entered_By, @Time_Entered);"

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MainSchedule.DataGridView1.Rows
                    If Not (row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing) Then
                        insertcommand.Parameters.Clear()
                        insertcommand.CommandText = query
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", row.Cells(0).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Complete", "False")
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", row.Cells(1).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_date", row.Cells(2).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Due_Date", row.Cells(3).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JRID", txtJRID.Text)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task_Manager", row.Cells(4).Value)
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entered_By", GetUserName())
                        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time_Entered", Now)
                        insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If
                    keypos = keypos + 1
                Next

                Connexion.Close()
```